# How to play music stored in SD card 540 Lumia

Tags: 8.1

Please explain how to play music stored on SD card in 540 LUMIA MOBILE

Answer (score 1):

Move all your Music files into **Music** folder of your SD card.

You can add MP3, M4A (AAC), and WMA music files to your Music folder.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 Mobile picks the content (Music, Videos, Photos, Documents etcetera) from default folders (On SD Card & on Internal memory). So move the Music to default folder (SD Card or Internal Memory) & wait for Groove Music Player to finish sync of music collection. It should work.